# figures and text do not appear in the right order

Tags: graphics, floats

That's my code

```
\subsection{Here is the subsection}
 Here is the text\\
 \begin{figure}[htbp]
     \centerline{\resizebox{\width}{5cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{r1.png}}}
     \caption{Here goes the caption.}
 \end{figure}
 More text\\
 \begin{figure}[htbp]
     \centerline{\resizebox{\width}{5cm}{\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{e1.png}}}
     \caption{Here goes the caption.}
 \end{figure}
 More text\\
 \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centerline{\includegraphics[scale=0.35]{r_e1.png}}
    \caption{Here goes the caption.}
 \end{figure}
```

The order in which they appear on the pdf is: 
1.Text all together at the beginning of the subsection 
2.all figures. 
Before I added the captions I think there was no such problem. Any clue?

Comment: This post has been flagged for migration to [tex.se].

Comment: You'll find your answer in [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://goo.gl/Qzz31)

Comment: Ok it worked after a while with [h!] thanks

Comment: Don't use `\centerline`. Use `\centering`.

Comment: @Werner When you use short URLs like that, the site does not recognise them which makes a lot more work when trying to mark a question as a duplicate!

Comment: @cfr: I know. I post short URLs on [so] because comments with target-site links vanish upon migration. Using the short URL will ensure that comments (and their associated links) don't get removed automatically. However, this does not work the same when dealing with magic links (`[so]`, `[tex.se]`, ...); they always remain.

Comment: @Werner Thanks for the explanation: it is because it is migrated. Seems like a shortcoming of the site software if it loses such links, but still.